# Inserted object is not reflected in the query results with NSFetchRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I've just started playing with the iOS development and Core Data technology.

What I am trying to do is to insert object into the Core Data and then run fetch request within same context looking for the newly inserted object.

Here is the code I am using to insert the object:

```
+(Reward*) rewardForAction: (Actions) action
    inManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Reward"];
    NSPredicate *actionPredicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"action = %@",
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", action]];

    NSPredicate *todayPredicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"when > %@",
         [NSDate today]];

    NSLog(@"Today's midnight :%@", [NSDate today]);
    request.predicate =
        [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
         [NSArray arrayWithObjects: actionPredicate, todayPredicate, nil]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest: request error: &error];

    Reward *reward = nil;
    if(!matches) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to retrieve rewards");
    } else if(matches.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"WRONG: reward already exists");
    } else {
        reward = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Reward"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:context];
        reward.action = [NSNumber numberWithInt:action];
        reward.when = [NSDate date];
        reward.pointsEarned = [Reward getPointsForAction:action];
    }

    [Stats track: context];

    [context save:nil];

    return reward;
}
```

This code first checks if reward is already given today for some action and if not it gives a reward.

calling this method twice with same parameters, like this

[Reward rewardForAction:APPLICATION_LAUNCH
 inManagedObjectContext: self.db.managedObjectContext];
[Reward rewardForAction:APPLICATION_LAUNCH
 inManagedObjectContext: self.db.managedObjectContext];

expected to result in inserting only one object.

But, in fact it inserts two objects into the Core Data. In the debugger I see second fetch request returns no objects when one is already there.

Looks like NSFetchRequest does not see changes in the data store and operating will on old data. Am I missing something ?

**EDIT:**
I have also set up observer for the NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification and when it gets called I am calculating sum of the points to reflect it on the UI. Unfortunately sum also does not contain points from the inserted object. Here is my code to calculate sum:

```
+(NSInteger) getPoints: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context {
    Stats * stats= [Stats get: context];

    NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                     [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"pointsEarned"]];
    NSExpression *ex = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
                                                 arguments:args];

    NSExpressionDescription *ed = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [ed setName:@"result"];
    [ed setExpression:ex];
    [ed setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ed]];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    /*if([stats intervalStartDate]) {
         NSPredicate *predicate =
            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"when >= %@", [stats intervalStartDate]];
             [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }*/    

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Reward"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    if(results && results.count > 0) {
        NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [results objectAtIndex:0];
        NSNumber *resultValue = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"result"];
        return [resultValue intValue];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

Strangely enough when I stop the app on the simulator and run it again. I can see all points as I expect.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies with one or both of your predicates.  Try commenting out request.predicate= and see if you're able to add two rows?  If not, then diagnose those predicates.

Comment: Indeed the problem was with the actionPredicate as pointed in the answer

Comment: I have another puzzle I put into the edit

Comment: use NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, not NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification. Check the docs

Comment: @DenysNikolayenko: You should start a new question instead of adding more questions to this one.

Comment: I am not sure why but changing from  NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification to NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification worked. Why running aggregate function right after changes to the object works on the old data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From

```
reward.action = [NSNumber numberWithInt:action];
```

I assume the "action" attribute is stored as `NSNumber`. You should use the same data type in the corresponding predicate:

```
NSPredicate *actionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"action = %@",
                                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:action]];
```

**ADDED:** To your question about "NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification" vs "NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification":

A fetch request with `NSDictionaryResultType` only fetches the current state in the persistent store , and does not take into account any pending changes, insertions, or deletions in the context.

You can find this information e.g. in the documentation of `setIncludesPendingChanges:`.

This explains why your fetch request sees only changes that have been saved.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help Martin, change from the string parameter to the NSNumber did help. Are predicates translated to the SQL syntax with the Core Data or there is some other mechanics behind this ? I didn't know how to to that correct, so I just used string assuming that if it converts to the SQL sytax there should be no problem, because SQLITE is not strongly typed.

Comment: I have another issue with the querying Core Data after inserting object that I did not mention initially. I have added it into the update and will appreciate if you can look at it.